# Clone-indirect-buffer repaints the source buffer as well as the clone

Tags: emacs

When I try to <kbd>C-x 4 c</kbd> on `org-mode` buffer visiting file and then switch to, say, `fundamental-mode` in the copy, the original buffer also switches to the fundamental, and if I switch the clone, the source follows. If I switch the original, the clone follows too.

Is this a bug, or do I need some special setting for it to happen?

This is Emacs 24.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. What I observe is that the one switched truly switches whereas the other one only loses font-lock. However the mode is not switched.